# Help understanding Mathematica's solution for $x^x=4$

Tags: logarithms, mathematica, lambert-w

> Solve for all $x$:$$x^x=4$$

If we take the $\ln$ of both sides, we get:
$$x\ln x=\ln 4$$
Since, $x=e^{\ln x}$, we get:
$$(\ln x)e^{\ln x}=\ln 4 \implies \ln x=W(\ln 4)\implies x=e^{W(\ln 4)}$$
Where $W(x)$ is the Lambert $W$ function. Now, based on my understanding, we should get:
$$x=e^{W(\ln 4)}e^{2\pi ik}=e^{W(\ln4)+2\pi ik}\qquad\forall k\in\mathbb N$$
However, Mathematica is telling me that one of the complete solutions to $x$ should be:
$$x=e^{W(2\pi ik+\ln x)}\qquad\forall k\in\mathbb N$$
Checking Mathematica's answer numerically shows that it is a wrong answer, so what gives?

Comment: I think this question must be done [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: by the other side if $x^x$ is complex then you cant take logarithms to both sides as you did, that is $x^x:=e^{x\ln x}$, assuming that $\ln$ is the principal value of the logarithm, then $\ln(x^x)=x\ln x$ if and only if $x\ln x\in\Bbb R+i(-\pi,\pi]$. And whenever $\ln$ is multi-valued then $\ln(e^z)=z+2\pi i\Bbb Z$